# Keep program from accepting double value when int is necessary

Tags: java, input, int, double

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );   
System.out.println("Input the minimum necessary word count in a single article!");
int minArticleLength1 = input.nextInt();
while (minArticleLength1<0){
    System.out.println("Input the minimum necessary word count in a single article!");
    minArticleLength1 = input.nextInt();
}
```

As you see in this part of program you are required to assign a value to int type variable. Everything works fine if i enter int type value however if i assign a value like 1.1 the program starts an infinite loop until i stop it. What should i change in the code to keep the program from accepting double value even though int is necessary so that if i would input double value like 1.1 the program would ask to enter the value again?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `try...catch` statement in your loop to catch invalid input.

```
while (minArticleLength1 < 0){
    System.out.println("Input the minimum necessary word count in a single article!");
    try {
        minArticleLength1 = input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException imex) }
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer.");
        minArticleLength1.nextLine();
    }
}
```